# Personalized-Mailer-CodeIgniter-Spark

Tags: codeigniter

I m using personalized mailer library in Codeigniter for sending emails to customers, mails are going perfectly but how can i get bounced email list. Please help me how to do this...Thanks

Comment: If you're using the SMTP send then you'll get the bounces in the inbox of the account you're sending from.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately servers are not required to send a rejected email request.  And those that do, have no standard way of doing so.  The gmails and hotmails might, but you cant rely on a response.

If you think about it, it would be a great security concern if that were allowed as you could check for all valid emails at a domain.